# reindex elasticsearch with version on type

Tags: elasticsearch, reindex

Here is my usecase : 
I have an ES index (myindex) 
In this index, I have 2 document types (myindex/mydoc , myindex/yourdoc) 
I have defined a mapping for this type (myindex/mydoc/_mapping)

I put many documents in this index (with default options so json source id stored in _source).

I want now to modify my mapping and ask to ES to reindex all my documents with type (myindex/mydoc), based on the _source.

I read lots of blogs saying that re-indexing should create an new index for the new mappings.

But in this way, we have to reindex both types into new index.

Just wondering if we add the version number on the type ( make it like myindex/mydoc_v1,  myindex/mydoc_v2 ) and then just reindex myindex/mydoc_v1 into myindex/mydoc_v2

Thanks for your feedbacks/advices 
Wallace

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is that  it is better to add version on type instead of indice ?